# Appsync VTL foreach loop limit of 101

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

When I try to return a `#foreach` loop in VTL response template even though I have 116 items it never returns more than 101. For testing I created two fields `items` and `itemCount` and ran same ES query.

VTL response mapping for `items`:

```
[
  #foreach($entry in $context.result)
    #if( $velocityCount > 1 ) , #end
    $util.toJson($entry.get("_source"))
  #end
]
```

VTL response mapping for `itemCount`:

```
$context.result.size()
```

It seems that there is a limit set on foreach loop by appsync (reference: http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch05s04.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just updated this limit to 1000, which is updated in the [AppSync limits page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_appsync).

Comment: Thanks @JeffBailey

Comment: Does this limit apply to each individual #foreach or for the entire VTL template? In other words if I had 2 back to back #foreach loops would they each be able to perform 1000 iterations?

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting around the arbitrary Velocity `directive.foreach.maxloops = 1000` limit set by AppSync and API Gateway is to break up your `foreach` loops by partitioning in buckets of 1000. Here is a working example:

```
## Partition to get around foreach iteration limit
#set($partition_size = 1000)
#set($max_partition_index = $list.size()/$partition_size)
#foreach($partition_index in [0..$max_partition_index])
  #set($start_index = $partition_index * $partition_size)
  #if($partition_index == $max_partition_index)
    ## Last partition
    #set($end_index = $list.size() - 1)
  #else
    #set($end_index = (($partition_index + 1) * $partition_size) - 1)
  #end

  #foreach($index in [$start_index..$end_index])
    #if($index != 0),#end
    "$list[$index].S"
  #end
#end
```

Comment: For the people that might use this. Pay attention to the trailing "," in the last if-statement. This is necessary for the original question but you might not need it in other use cases.